# Understanding C variables

Tags: c

It takes n - range of series - and then ask for elements of that series. Then it should returns max number but it always returns 49. If I use `gdb` I can say that even before place where this variable is inicialized it has value 49. I don't know why and how to fix this. 
I have an easy C program like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int T[1000];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int m;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", T + i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (T[i] > m)
            m = T[i];

    printf("max: %d\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `42` would make more sense..

Comment: `42` is my everyday workplace number, really ;)

Comment: **Always compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.** You'll find yourself asking much fewer questions about why code is behaving strangely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is not initialized in your program.

Initialize it to `0`:

```
int m = 0;
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you. After 10 minutes I will approve the answer.

Comment: `m = T[0];` before the second `for` loop would be better, so the program would also work if the inputs are all negative.

Comment: @mch or `int m =  INT_MIN;` for negative inputs, but `m = T[0]` is even better.